# IBM Cloud Functions: How to run a Docker function?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions, ibm-cloud-code-engine

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY ./src /data/python
WORKDIR /data/python
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir flask
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

- main.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return {'body': os.environ.items()}


def run():
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

click invoke result

```
[
  "2021-01-29T09:53:30.727847Z    stdout: * Serving Flask app \"main\" (lazy loading)",
  "2021-01-29T09:53:30.727905Z    stdout: * Environment: production",
  "2021-01-29T09:53:30.727913Z    stdout: WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.",
  "2021-01-29T09:53:30.727918Z    stdout: Use a production WSGI server instead.",
  "2021-01-29T09:53:30.727923Z    stdout: * Debug mode: off",
  "2021-01-29T09:53:30.731130Z    stderr: * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)",
  "2021-01-29T09:53:30.747035Z    stderr: 172.30.139.167 - - [29/Jan/2021 09:53:30] \"\u001b[33mPOST /init HTTP/1.1\u001b[0m\" 404 -",
  "2021-01-29T09:53:30.748Z       stderr: The action did not initialize or run as expected. Log data might be missing."
]
```

I've added the Docker container to IBM Cloud Functions

What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Docker images which are uploaded to IBM Cloud Functions must implement certain REST interfaces. The easiest way to achieve this is to base your container on the `openwhisk/dockerskeleton`image.

Please see
[How to run a docker image in IBM Cloud functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56431437/how-to-run-a-docker-image-in-ibm-cloud-functions)
and https://github.com/iainhouston/dockerPython
for more details

Answer (score 0):

The docs for IBM Cloud Functions have some pointers on [how to create Docker-based functions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=openwhisk-runtimes#openwhisk_ref_docker). IMHO Cloud Functions are more for short-running serverless workloads and I would like to point you to another serverless technology in the form of [IBM Cloud Code Engine](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-application-workloads). Its model is based on Docker containers and one of its use cases are http-based web applications, e.g., like your Flask app.

You would define the Dockerfile as you want, don't need a special skeleton and could just follow this [guide on Dockerfile best practices for Code Engine](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-dockerfile).